# CUDA FORTRAN: function gives different answer if I pass variable instead of number

Tags: function, cuda, fortran

I'm trying to use the `ISHFT()` function to bitshift some 32-bit integers in parallel, using CUDA FORTRAN.

The problem is that I get different answers to `ISHFT(-4,-1)` and `ISHFT(var,-1)` even though `var = -4`. This is the test code I've written:

```
module testshift 

  integer :: test 
  integer, device :: d_test 

contains 

  attributes(global) subroutine testshft () 
    integer :: var
    var = -4
    d_test = ISHFT(var,-1)
  end subroutine testshft

end module testshift

program foo 
  use testshift 

  integer :: i
  call testshft<<<1,1>>>() ! carry out ishft on gpu
  test = d_test            ! copy device result to host
  i = ISHFT(-4,-1)         ! carry out ishft on cpu
  print *, i, test         ! print the results
end program foo
```

I then compile and execute:

```
pgf90 testishft.f90 -Mcuda
./a.out 
   2147483646           -2
```

Both should be 2147483646 if working correctly. I get the right answer if I replace `var` with `4`.

How do I fix this problem?
Thanks for the help

Comment: hmm, have you tried tracing the problem using emulation mode `–Mcuda=emu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround, which is posted in this forum:
http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=2455&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15

Instead of using ISHFT I use IBITS, which is described here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IBITS.html

Also the problem has since been fixed in version 11.3 of the PGI compiler
http://www.pgroup.com/support/release_tprs_2011.htm

Answer (score 1):

When I remove the GPU-specific code from the above program I get 2147483646 2147483646 from the g95 compiler, as you expect. Have you tried running a "scalar" version of the program using the pgf90 compiler? If the scalar version works but the GPU version does not, that helps to isolate the problem. If the problem is pgf90/CUDA specific, perhaps the best place to ask your question is

PGI User Forum Forum Index -> Programming and Compiling
http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewforum.php?f=4 .

Comment: The scalar version works fine, I can pass a variable into the ISHFT() function and it gives me the right answer. The only thing that doesn't work is when passing a variable into the GPU version. I've asked a similar question on the pgi user forum http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=2455&sid=6dedb3c189bd64506e9ff883741c2e4f but I'm worried that I'll be convicted of reposting if I try to post a simpler version of the question like the one posted here